# How to use routing in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes

How to use Routing in CodeIgniter? I've tried but no result. Here's my view:

```html
<a href="/survey/index.php/index/student_surveys/1/" class='btn btn-success'>  1 </a>
<a href='/survey/index.php/index/student_surveys/2/'class='btn btn-success'>  2 </a>
<a href='/survey/index.php/index/student_surveys/3/'class='btn btn-success'>  3 </a>
```

I tried with this:

```html
$route['survey/index.php/index/student_surveys/1/'] = 'index/student_surveys/1/';
$route['survey/index.php/index/student_surveys/2/'] = 'index/student_surveys/1/';
```

But when I changed link to test, it doesn't change. It works only with my links not with routing. My controller is:

```html
 public function student_surveys() {
$this->form_validation->set_rules('teacher', 'Teacher', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'Subject', 'required|callback_subject'); 
        if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
        {
            $this->student_surveys_show();
        } 
        else 
        {
$this->user_model->add_teacher_subject();
 redirect('/index/survey_show/' . $survey_id);
            }               
            
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried, `$this->load->view('survey_show',$survey_id,TRUE);` ?

Comment: I want to use routes. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
$route['confirm_registration/(:any)']=  "login/confirm_registration/$1";
```

Comment: Yes, but I have 3 links, it should redirect to "login/confirm_registration/$1"; if $route['confirm_registration/1'], "login/confirm_registration/$2";  if 'confirm_registration/2'

Comment: No, You don't need to $3 or $4, add $1 it replace with your count